# Why does this sequence not oscillate?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, oscillatory-integral

I'm confused on why this sequence converges to 0 rather than diverge because of an oscillating series, since the result would be negative if n is odd and positive if n is even

Edit for the downvote: I apologize that my question was simple, but I genuinely thought it through for a while and could not understand. I was hoping I could ask the smart and giving people of Stack Exchange in order to enlighten me.

[image]

Comment: It does oscillate between positive and negative terms. However, since it oscillates between numbers that get smaller and smaller in absolute value as $n$ increases, it converges to $0$.

Comment: Just guessing, not the downvoter: The downvote probably reflects not the simplicity of the question, but the fact that the mathematical content is an image, which isn't [accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility). Typing the content of the question in MathJaX would be welcome, in any case. (The downvoter may also have taken exception to the use of "series" when "sequence" was meant; the terms are not interchangeable here.)

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0$, we have

$$a_{2n}=\frac{2n}{8n^3+1}>0$$

and

$$a_{2n+1}=-\frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)^3+1}<0$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n}=0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{2n+1}=0$$

So,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice we have: If $|a_n| \to 0$, then $a_n \to 0$ because of

$$ - |a_n| \leq a_n \leq |a_n| $$

and the squeeze rule